# Devexpress - Output selected Rows to label

Tags: c#, devexpress

I am trying to output my selected rows in the AspxGridView to a label to see what has been selected. However the result is "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]" Rather than the text in column called "ID"

```
protected void Button13_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> itemList = new List<string>();
        Label2.Text = string.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i < ASPxGridView1.VisibleRowCount; i++)
        {
            if (ASPxGridView1.Selection.IsRowSelected(i))
            {
                itemList.Add(ASPxGridView1.GetSelectedFieldValues("ID").ToString());


            }
        }
        Label2.Text = string.Join("<br />", itemList);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select one row only and get its values on a click, I advise you to use the **FocusedRowChanged** event of the ASPxGridView. 
To use it, you first need to enable FocusedRow.
Then if you want "ID" only, you can select it directly

```
Label2.Text = string.Join("<br />", ASPxGridView1.GetSelectedFieldValues("ID").ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
foreach (var dt in ASPxGridView1.GetSelectedFieldValues("ID").ToList())
{
   Label2.Text = Label2.Text + dt;
}
```